# Is it possible to skip buildSrc project in a multi-module Gradle build?

Tags: build, gradle

We are in the early stage of migrating from a complex Maven build system to hopefully a simpler Gradle build system. Unfortunately I put some of our own custom Maven plugin extensions into /buildSrc.

Is it possible to skip the internal buildSrc project with Gradle? I'd rather not build what's in this directory at this time.

Eventually it would be replaced with our own custom Gradle plugins but for now I would ideally want to skip this project entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`buildSrc` will get built as soon as the directory exists. So the best way is to delete or rename that directory.

Another option would be to add a `buildSrc/build.gradle` containing `tasks.all { enabled = false }`. Not quite the same as skipping the project entirely, though.